# Windows server 2008 change admin password

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I Have a os windows server 2008 in my Laptop with domain name. Recently when i start os and i put the password but it says reset the password so i put new password so appaer the message is that "Unable to update the Password.the value provided for the new password does not meet the length,complexeity or history requirements of the domain". Now i cannot open the Windows so please inform me solution.

Answer (score 2):

You've obviously not met the password complexity policy set at a domain or group level and made this mistake enough times to lock your account. You need to a) speak to your domain administration team to get them to explain the policy to you and fix it this time and b) read our FAQ as this was an inappropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Create a password that meets the length, complexity, and history requirements of the domain. You can find out what those requirements are by checking under "Account Policies -> Password Policy" using secpol.msc on a domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Have your network administrator A) Make sure your Active Directory user account is not locked and B) Reset your password for you (and possible adjust the expiration date).  Also, you might want to ask him what the password requirements are.